# how i can key interrupt ctrl+c?

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

[full coding](https://gist.github.com/riki745/cd2e143d80e2f09fe3282bafaa40431b)

```
start = time.time()
file = open('python.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()

p = Pool(processes=1)
try:
    result = p.map(checkurl, urls)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print("done in : ", time.time() - start)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('ctrl+c on!')
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
```